# How can I get Annotation class from TypeDescription

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm trying to work with ByteBuddy.

How, with given `TypeDescription`, can I get annotation class?

So far I found `getActualName`.

```
@Override
public boolean matches(final TypeDescription target) {
    //System.out.printf("matches(%1$s)\n", target);
    //System.out.printf("\tcanonicalName: %1$s\n", target.getCanonicalName());
    //System.out.printf("\tcomponentType: %1$s\n", target.getComponentType());
    {
        final AnnotationList inheritedAnnotations = target.getInheritedAnnotations();
        inheritedAnnotations.forEach(v -> {
            //System.out.printf("\tinherited annotationDescriptor: %1$s\n", v);
        });
    }
    {
        final AnnotationList declaredAnnotations = target.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        declaredAnnotations.forEach(v -> {
            //System.out.printf("\tdeclared annotationDescriptor: %1$s\n", v);
        });
    }
    {
        final FieldList<FieldDescription.InDefinedShape> declaredFields = target.getDeclaredFields();
        declaredFields.forEach(declaredFiled -> {
            System.out.println("declaredField: " + declaredFiled);
            final AnnotationList declaredAnnotations = declaredFiled.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            declaredAnnotations.forEach(declaredAnnotation -> {
                System.out.println("declaredAnnotation: {}" + declaredAnnotation);
                final Set<ElementType> elementTypes = declaredAnnotation.getElementTypes();
                System.out.println("\telementTypes: " + elementTypes);
                final TypeDescription annotationType = declaredAnnotation.getAnnotationType();
                System.out.println("\tannotationType: " + annotationType);
                System.out.println("\tannotationType.actualName: " + annotationType.getActualName());
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm, actually, trying to add some methods on compiled classes by some fields annotated with specific annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AnnotationList` is a list of `AnnotationDescription` typed object where you can invoke the `getAnnotationType` method to receive a `TypeDescription` of their annotation type.

Comment: Thanks. How can I compare `TypeDescription` with specific annotation `Class<?>`? Other than `getActualName`?

Comment: By `typeDescription.represents(SomeClass.class)`.